# LXC: Failed to pass wlan0 interface physically to container

Tags: networking, wifi, lxc, container

I am trying to move `wlan0` interface from host to container with the below configuration,

```
lxc.network.type = phys
lxc.network.link = wlan0
lxc.network.hwaddr = ab:cd:ef:gh:ij
lxc.network.flags = up
```

Which works perfectly with my external TP-Link wifi dongle and I can see `wlan0` interface available inside the container by running `ifconfig`

But I do also have an integrated ALPS wifi chip for which the same container configuration won't work and fails with the below error.

```
lxc-start 20170704134254.641 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_assign_network:3102 - failed to move 'wlan0' to the container : Operation not permitted
      lxc-start 20170704134254.641 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1199 - Failed to create the configured network.
      lxc-start 20170704134254.641 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_delete_network:2926 - Interface "eth0" with index 6 already deleted or existing in different network namespace.
      lxc-start 20170704134254.710 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_delete_network:2961 - Removed interface "vethQVT9W2" from host.
      lxc-start 20170704134254.711 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1338 - Failed to spawn container "my-cont".
      lxc-start 20170704134254.779 WARN     lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_recv:172 - command get_cgroup failed to receive response
      lxc-start 20170704134259.784 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:360 - The container failed to start.
      lxc-start 20170704134259.784 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:362 - To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
      lxc-start 20170704134259.784 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:364 - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

I have also found a [**thread**](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-devel/2009-June/000197.html) where it says till `sysfs` virtualization is not finalized the kernel will have this limitation.

If that's the case, how did it worked for my external wifi dongle?

Or is it something else which I'm missing?